# Workflow foundation support in coreclr

Tags: coreclr

Is workflow foundation supported in core CLR? We are planning to use Docker container and deploy in Linux and plan to use workflow foundation features. I could not find the information in https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Microsoft has no active plan for porting Workflow Foundation to .NET Core. However, there is [a ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2394) discussing the details.